# How can I change the index of a PivotTable

Tags: excel, vba, indexing, pivot

I am trying to automatically mail some reports (which are essentially Pivot Tables) using VBA script. I have multiple Pivot tables in some of my sheets. How do I ensure that a particular Pivot Table is always indexed as 1.

Example:

On a worksheet I two Pivot Tables - PvtTable1 & PvtTable2. In my VBA code, when I reference a Pivot Table using the code, ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1) I want it to always refer it to PvtTable1. Not PvtTable. How can I do that? I don't want to refer my Pivot Tables using their names, as I intend to use my VBA code in a FOR LOOP.

```
Dim current As Worksheet

For Each current In Worksheets
         <my VBA Code statements>
         Set PvtTableRng = current.PivotTables(1).TableRange1
         <some more VBA Code>
Next
```

Comment: Use the name, not the index number.

Comment: As mentioned, I cannot use Name. I am looking at how to ensure that a particular Pivot table is always indexed as 1 & another one as 2 etc. & so on. Any help on how I can set the the Index Value of Pivot Table is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken (duh) the index of a pivot table (or shape, or anything really) depends on the order of creation; thus to reindex, you need to recreate the pivots in the same order you want them. Or you could name them "Pivot1", "Pivot2", ..."Pivot42", and then retrieve them ...by name rather than by index, by concatenating "Pivot" with your current for loop index

Comment: Well thats what I also thought and did recreate the Pivot Tables in the order that I want. However it doesn't seem to work. Everytime I save the file & reopen the Index changes. You see I don;t want to rather complicate my code (being a novice at VBA). My goal is simple. Just take the "1st" Pivot table in every sheet and mail them.